# Vue component - how to avoid mutating a prop (Laravel component)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I get the following warning with my Vue component for Laravel:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever
the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the
prop's value. Prop being mutated: "benutzers"

found in

---> <BootstrapVueBTable1> at resources/js/components/b-table1.vue
       <Root>
```

I tried some variations of renaming, but I am not experienced.

```
<template>
  <div> <b-table striped hover :items="benutzers" > </b-table> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      this.loadData();
    },
    methods: {
      loadData:function() {
        axios.get('/api/benutzers').then(res => {
          if(res.status == 200) {
            this.benutzers = res.data;
          }
        }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err)
        });
      }
    },
    props: ['benutzers'],
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in some case you're still overwriting your props if you use

```
<div v-for="benutzer in  parentbenutzers">
```

so you need to change your v-for to this

```
<div v-for="benutzer in  benutzers">

      props: ['parentBenutzers'],
data() {
  return {
    benutzers: this.parentBenutzers,
  }
},
mounted(){
    this.loadData();
},
methods:{
    loadData:function(){
        axios.get('/api/benutzers').then(res=>{
          if(res.status==200){
             this.benutzers=res.data;
          }
        }).catch(err=>{
           console.log(err)
        });
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the is telling you that you should avoid using `benutzers` being passed as a prop because its value may be overwritten when calling your component. Also, you are overwriting the value yourself inside your method `loadData`.

The best way to avoid issues with this value is to store it inside your component's store OR using a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Try using `data` instead:

```js
export default {
  mounted(){
    this.loadData();
  },
  
  data: {
    benutzers: [],
  },

  methods: {
    loadData: function() {
      axios.get('/api/benutzers').then(res=>{
        if(res.status==200){
          this.benutzers = res.data; 
          //i'm not sure if it's this.benutzers or just benutzers, but this should solve your problem
        }
      }).catch( err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
    }
  },
}
```

Check out Vue's doc to understand [how to use `data` in loops](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Conditionals-and-Loops).

Comment: have to add the return clause in the data part :-)

Answer (score 1):

There might be better ways to do this depending on the behavior you need, but you can avoid mutating the prop by making a new field in `data` that watches the `prop` for mutations. This will allow both the  parent and child component to mutate the value in the child.

```
props: ['parentBenutzers'],
data() {
  return {
    benutzers: this.parentBenutzers,
  }
},
watch: {
  parentBenutzers: function(val) {
    this.benutzers = val;
  }
},
mounted(){
    this.loadData();
},
methods:{
    loadData:function(){
        axios.get('/api/benutzers').then(res=>{
          if(res.status==200){
             this.benutzers=res.data;
          }
        }).catch(err=>{
           console.log(err)
        });
    }
},
```

Answer (score -1):

oh, just a second answer... thanks, i test this too with the parent-child-thing, one moment please, ok that works too. Even if I do not understand the difference (yet)

both answers work ... the correct code is below. Had so much things tried before, also the data thing. But when i tried that, i had the error into the template part ... sometimes You're so deep in the maze you can't see over the wall ... in any case thank you very much for your helping answers Laryssa and Jared

```
<template>
    <div> <b-table striped hover :items="benutzers" > </b-table> 
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
  mounted(){
    this.loadData();
  },

  data() {
      return{
    benutzers: [],
  }
  },
  methods: {
    loadData: function() {
      axios.get('/api/benutzers').then(res=>{
        if(res.status==200){
          this.benutzers = res.data; 
          //i'm not sure if it's this.benutzers or just benutzers, but this should solve your problem
        }
      }).catch( err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
    }
  },
}
</script>
```